# Command line: <<< instead of <<

Tags: shell, io-redirection

Why is the command `md5sum <<< 'ddd'`
(output: `d6d88f2e50080b9602da53dac1102762  -`)
right, and `md5sum << 'ddd'` not?

What does `<<<` mean?

Comment: [What's the difference between <<, <<< and < < in bash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678915/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-bash)

Answer (score 62):

The `<<<` starts a “here string”: The string is expanded and fed to the program’s stdin. (In your case, there is not much of expansion happening.) It is equivalent to this:

```
echo ddd | md5sum
```

On the other hand, `<<` starts a here document. All the following lines up to one containing the marker `ddd` will comprise the input of the program. (You should use a marker that is not likely to appear in your data.) You could achieve the same effect as above like this:

```
md5sum <<END
ddd
END
```

There is one difference between `<<END` and `<<'END'`: Without the quotes, any variables, escape sequences etc. in the here document will be expanded as usual.

Comment: Where it's not equivalent is that except in `rc`, `<<<` (like `<<`) uses a temporary file so can be used by commands that `lseek` their stdin.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas, where this temporary is created? I've tried to start using `<<` and in other window typed `ls -la` in same folder and have not seen any new files (Mac OS).

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov, it's deleted after it's opened but before it's being used which ensures it's not left behind, so it's only visible on the file system for a very short time. On Linux `ls -ld /proc/self/fd/0 <<< text` will show you its original path with a `" (deleted)"` appended. It's generally in `$TMPDIR` or `/tmp` if `$TMPDIR` is not set. `zsh` uses `$TMPPREFIX` instead (a prefix, not a directory).

Comment: So would it be correct to say that a here-string `<<<` doesn't need closing, and is typically all on a single line?

Answer (score 42):

`<<<` introduces a [here string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings): the string after `<<<` is passed as input to the command. This originates in Byron Rakitzis's implementation of `rc` (a Plan 9 shell) for Unix, and is also present in zsh, ksh93, mksh, yash and bash.

`<<` introduces a [here document](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents): subsequent lines of the shell script are passed as input to the command, and the string after `<<` is a terminator. Here documents work in all Bourne-style shells (Bourne, POSIX, ash, bash, ksh, zsh, …), C-style shells (csh, tcsh), and shells derived from the Plan 9 shell (rc, es, akanga).

Comment: No, `<<<` is not a `ksh` extension, the path is `rc` -> `zsh` -> `ksh93` -> `bash` (`ksh` release notes acknowledge for once borrowing the feature from `zsh`). `<<` also works in `rc` style shells

Comment: There's a difference between the `rc` and `zsh` `<<<` though in that `rc`'s doesn't include a trailing newline character and doesn't use a temp file (uses a pipe and an extra process feeding it at least in the port to Linux).