# inline heredoc instead of file

Tags: command-line, pipe, command-substitution, here-document

I have a command (php file) which takes, as an argument, the location of a file.

eg.

`$ php ./ScriptName.php /my/file/location.txt`

Sometimes I only need one or two words, so I don't really want to create the location.txt file just so I can reference it with the next command - I'd rather pipe it with the command somehow. For example, consider the contents of `location.txt` from the above example being just:

`mywords`

Is there a way I can rewrite that original commandline argument to just provide the contents of a "virtual" file?

Comment: See [here-strings](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76402/command-line-instead-of)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a variant of the [`/dev/fd/0` trick](https://askubuntu.com/questions/854921/how-to-replace-an-output-filename-by-a-custom-command-that-use-output/854928#854928) to pass a string to a script which expects a file name:

```
php ./ScriptName.php php://fd/0 <<<'mywords'
```

For example, script.php contains:

```
<?php
   $handle=fopen($argv[1],"r");
   echo "Read: ".fgets($handle);
   fclose($handle);
?>
```

Running:

```
php script.php php://fd/0 <<<'Some text'
```

outputs:

```
Read: Some text
```

Comment: Running `GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)` this did not work - I got `Warning: fopen(/dev/fd/0): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: Perhaps this is more of a problem with php `fopen` than bash...

Comment: Sorry, I was way behind the times. Edited answer with the correct syntax accepted by PHP independent of the shell.

Comment: Thank you, your example and commands do work. I am actually trying to pipe this through the symfony console, which is still giving me trouble though. Perhaps I will re-ask on SO for the symfony specific nature of this now.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a shell that allows process substitution such as zsh, bash or ksh, you could do

```
php ScriptName.php <(echo mywords)
```

The shell will set up some method to run the echo command in a different shell, and make the output available either as a named fifo or more commonly via a pipe and a filename of the form /dev/fd/XX.

Comment: Running `GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)` this did not work - I got `Warning: fopen(/dev/fd/63): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: Perhaps this is more of a problem with php `fopen` than bash...