# Testing for presence of duplicate values in array

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to find a simple way to just test an array for duplicate values. It would be nice, but not completely necessary, to be able to identify the specific lines that have duplicates, but the important point is simply being able to see that there's a duplicate.

I have an array, `$key_array`, which contains some numbers:

```
# echo ${key_array[@]}
1 2 3 4 3 3
```

This array could have an arbitrary number of numbers, some of which could be duplicates of others. They will be integer numbers only. (Numbers beginning with a `0`, such as `03`, should not make into the array at all, but in the off-chance that it happens, catching `3` and `03` as a duplicate of each other would be better than treating them as different numbers.)

I need to determine if any of these numbers are duplicates. I was thinking this could be done with an exit code if nothing else. What I was after was something like this:

```
if $(some command); then
 echo "Array contains duplicates."
 exit 1
fi
$(commands to run after duplicate check)
```

The idea being in the end that the script informs the user and exits if there are duplicates (not super important to identify where the duplicates are, just telling the user to check for duplicates is enough), or if there aren't any duplicates, it proceeds and runs a bunch of other stuff.

How would I best accomplish this?

Comment: Should 3 be considered a duplicate of 03? Is the array of integers only?

Comment: @Quasímodo it's integers only. numbers beginning with a 0 such as 03 should not make into the array at all, but in the off-chance that it happens, catching them as a duplicate would be better than treating them as different numbers.

Comment: `$()` in `if $(some command); then` is not necessary. The if construct by default takes a list (a sequence of one or more pipelines) and executes them, testing their exit status. Thus, `if some command; then` is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `arr` contains only integers and that zero padded numbers should be considered duplicates (e.g., `01` is a duplicate of `1`), we can use a second array to keep the values already "seen" when parsing each element of the first array `arr`.

```
#!/bin/bash
arr=(1 2 3 4 3 3)
seen=()

for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
    #Remove padding zeroes, if any
    i=$((10#$i))
    # If element of arr is not in seen, add it as a key to seen
    if [ -z "${seen[i]}" ]; then
        seen[i]=1
    else
        echo "Array contains a duplicate."
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: Note that that assumes array elements are decimal integers (there's also the question of whether 01 and 1 should be deemed duplicate of each other).

Comment: Since Bash 4.0 you may use an associative array to not have subscripts treated as arithmetic expressions. (That wouldn't properly treat them as "numbers" either, of course).

Comment: Tested it out, and this worked perfectly for what I need.

Comment: Note that the array elements here are interpreted as arithmetic expressions (so `1+1` is the same as `2` or `" 2 "` or `18446744073709551618`  and `RANDOM` will likely be different from `RANDOM`). For that reason, it's also important the values are sanitized as otherwise that introduces a command injection vulnerability.

Comment: Note that since `bash` interprets numbers with leading 0s as octal, `010` will be considered the same as 8, not 10.

Comment: I think all you need to make that work with string values is to initialize `seen` with `declare -A seen=()`, and indexing it as `"${seen[$i]}"` and `seen[$i]=1` (instead of indexing with just `[i]`)

Comment: Note that the `i=$((10#$i))` work around doesn't work for negative numbers, where `10#-010` is interpreted as `10#0 - 010`, so `0 - 8` so `-8`.

Comment: @ilkkachu, with the caveat that bash associative arrays don't support empty  strings in their keys (which can be worked around by adding a prefix for instance).

Answer (score 5):

In the `zsh` shell:

```
array=(1 2 3 4 3 3)
if (($#array != ${#${(u)array}})); then
  print -u2 array contains duplicates
  exit 1
fi
```

Where `${(u)array}` expands to the unique elements of the array, so we're just comparing the number of elements with the number of unique elements.

The `bash` shell doesn't have an equivalent, but as its arrays can't contain NUL bytes anyway, if you're on a GNU system, you could do something like:

```
readarray -td '' dups < <(
  (( ${#array[@]} == 0 )) ||
    printf '%s\0' "${array[@]}" |
      LC_ALL=C sort -z |
      LC_ALL=C uniq -zd
)

if ((${#dups[@]} > 0)); then
  echo >&2 "array has duplicates:"
  printf >&2 ' - "%s"\n' "${dups[@]}"
  exit 1
fi
```

In those, elements are considered *duplicate* if they are byte-to-byte identical, not if their numeric value if any is the same (`1`, `01`, `0x1`, `1e0`, `2-1`, `$'1\n'`, `' 1'` are all considered different).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `key_array` array only ever contains whole numbers (positive integers), we may use the fact that ordinary arrays are *sparse* in the `bash` shell.  The following code is looping over the array of keys while instantiating elements in a regular array until we find a key that we have already processed:

```bsh
key_array=( '09' 1 2 3 4 3 3 '04' '001' '07' )

has_dupes () (
        unset -v a

        for key do
                ${a[10#$key]+'return'}  # execute "return" if a[10#$key] is set
                a[10#$key]=             # set a[10#$key] to empty string
        done

        return 1
)

if has_dupes "${key_array[@]}"; then
        echo 'array has dupes'
else
        echo 'array has no dupes'
fi
```

This introduces a utility function, `has_dupes`, that takes a list of whole numbers, and returns zero if there is a duplicate value in the list and non-zero if there are no duplicated values.

The standard parameter expansion `${variable+word}` is used to insert the word `return` if `a[10#$key]` was previously set. When `return` is substituted, it terminates the function's execution and returns a zero exit status to the caller signifying that we found a duplicate value.  The index `10#$key` means "the value `$key` interpreted as a base 10 integer" and allows us to equate keys like `03` and `3`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need it to work in Bash 3.X, you could use `uniq`:

`IFS=$'\n' sort <<<"${key_array[*]}" | uniq -d; unset IFS`

This will return with, and only with, all duplicate elements of the array.

**Description**

1. `IFS=$'\n'` sets the [internal field separator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184863/what-is-the-meaning-of-ifs-n-in-bash-scripting) to a new line character, ensuring that `"${key_array[*]}"` will expand into a single line per array element.
2. `<<<` is a [here string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76402/command-line-instead-of) that feeds the output of `"${key_array[*]}"` into the standard input of `sort`.
3. `sort` well, sorts.
4. `uniq -d` outputs "...a single copy of each line that is repeated in the input." (from `man uniq`).
5. `unset IFS` is [just good business](https://youtu.be/_54IUIv97nI?t=139), and resets `IFS` back to its default.

Comment: (1) You should explain exactly you believe that why the Bash version matters.  (2) This is very similar to the Bash part of [Stéphane Chazelas’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/606259/80216#606263).  (2b) As his answer foreshadows, ``sort`` and ``uniq`` may produce unexpected results in some locales.  (3) You say “`unset IFS` is just good business …”  I disagree.  This snippet may be used in a large script where `IFS` has been changed to something non-standard.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (See also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64173/80216 "What's a safe and portable way to split a string in shell programming?").)  (3b) And worst of all, you don’t need to reset ``IFS``.  Your command modifies `IFS` only for the scope of the `sort` command.  (4) The question asks for a test that can produce a yes-or-no answer in a script.  How does this produce a yes-or-no answer in a script? … … … (5) P.S. Thanks for including the explanation.